# Promise error propagation and capture

Tags: promise, bluebird

I can't seem to capture a `TypeError` myself, no matter where I place the [catch](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-errorclassfunction-predicate-function-handler---promise) block for bluebird ... it always seems to get picked up by bluebird's **catch-all** policy but not my own catch block:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot call method 'storeConfigModel' of null
...
  at tryCatcher (.../node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
```

What are some common mistakes that a dev can make that would cause such a scenario?

Here's my code snippet:

```
      .then(function(storeModelInstance) {
        log('print object for storeModelInstance: ', storeModelInstance);
        var storeConfigInstance = storeModelInstance.storeConfigModel(); // FAILS HERE
        log('print object for storeConfigInstance: ', storeConfigInstance);
        return Promise.resolve([reportModelInstance, storeModelInstance, storeConfigInstance]);
      })
      .catch(TypeError, function(error) {
        // WHY doesn't this pick up on TypeError in the above block?
        return Promise.reject(error);
      })
```

Comment: Surely it does get picked up, just put a `console.log` in that `catch`. The unhandled rejection is from `Promise.reject(error);` though! Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2):

It probably *is* picked up, but you subsequently "throw" it again:

```
return Promise.reject(error);
```